# SQL Server: pushing development to production?

Tags: sql-server, dbmigrate, database-deployment

I'm currently using SQL Server Management Studio.

I have a development database, and access to a live database.

I just want to able to migrate my development tables to the live server.

I'm consulting stack flow first, since I don't want to blow anything up.

Answer (score 2):

If you know what tables you want to migrate and they don't yet exist on the prod server, it's as simple as scripting the table definition, then running the script on the server.  If it's more complex than that, I would recommend any number of tools which compare database schemas and automatically generate scripts you can run on the destination server to add/alter/remove what you need.  A good freeware one for simple jobs is [DBComparer](http://www.dbcomparer.com/).  It's pretty basic.  An excellent commercial one are the [Sql Tools by Red Gate](http://www.red-gate.com/)

Comment: I'll trying the scripting method then.

Comment: Red Gate rocks.  I absolutely love their tools and at this point consider it the ONLY real way of migrating schemas between dev/stage/production.

Comment: Also, I've never had any luck with the microsoft tools.  Whether it be the stuff built in to management studio like Copy Database, import/export, and publish to web service or the ones included with Visual Studio Team like the Schema or Data compare.  For whatever reason they just can't get this right.  SQL Compare by redgate on the other hand has always worked flawlessly.

Comment: yea, I would love to have Red Gate at my disposal, but I've never worked anywhere that would spring for the cost.  That's why I use the DBComparer freeware right now for most of that stuff I need to do.

Answer (score 0):

We are using [SQL Examiner Suite](http://www.sqlaccessories.com/SQL_Examiner_Suite) for this, but there are a lot of similar tools.

Comment: There must be a way to do it in Managerment Studio though

Comment: VS2010 do it, but 3rd party tools are much more usable and powerfull

Answer (score 0):

This is worth a look at - I've used it before and it works well and is very easy: Microsoft SQL Server Database Publishing Wizard http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=56E5B1C5-BF17-42E0-A410-371A838E570A&displaylang=en